# Is a tapped creature an illegal target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing the Magic 2015 game on my xbox 360 (I know it has a lot of problems but its midly entertaining, I much prefer the card game though but this brought something to my attention and made me want to know if the game on box is wrong or if I am, since when I play with the cards I need to know the rules since we obviously won't just have a judge sitting there the whole time haha)

Pretty simple story
They attacked with a 4/1 (Don't remember what it was but it had no abilities) so after combat it became tapped

I cast [Flesh to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flesh%20to%20Dust) but it refused to let me target their tapped creature
Flesh to dust has no special rules on targetting just "Target creature"

I think it doesn't matter if their creature is tapped. Am I wrong?

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the body of the post are not the same. The title question is answerable. The question in the body of the post is a bug report in disguise, and is not answerable with the amount of information you have provided. Without screenshots of the board at the exact moment that the issue occurred, your graveyard, and your opponent's graveyard, how can we know whether this is a bug or whether you just missed something?

Comment: It was meant to be the same [Edit, I pressed post too early] I don't care if the game was bugged it was more of saying "Am I right about how I thought it worked or does it work the way it works in the game" I worded it wrong though you are right, I appolagize and will fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Flesh to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flesh%20to%20Dust) says "target creature", so the target must be a creature. Period. Whether it's tapped or not is of no consequence. Same goes for [Akroan Mastiff](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Akroan%20Mastiff)'s ability; it simply won't do anything on resolution if the creature is still tapped then.

Hexproof, Shroud, Protection and other abilities can impose additional limits. Don't forget that creatures can be granted abilities (e.g. [Lightning Greaves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Greaves)), and that creatures can be the subject of continuous effects created by abilities of other permanents.

Comment: Okay thanks, the creature had no abilities so I guess the game just wasn't working correctly

Comment: Don't forget that creatures can be granted abilities (e.g. Aerie Mystics), and that creatures can be the subject of continuous effects created by abilities of other permanents (e.g. Asceticism).

Answer (score 3):

Unless some other ability (such as Hexproof) or effect prevents it, [Flesh to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flesh%20to%20Dust) can target any creature. It says so on the card.

Flesh to Dust an Instant, so you can cast it whenever you have priority. You get priority during the declare attackers phase, so you should have the opportunity to cast Flesh to Dust.

---

**Phases behave differently in Magic 2015 for XBox 360.**

Unlike paper Magic, the game moves along without waiting for you. You only have a few seconds to cast spells after attackers are declared before the game decides that it is time for you to declare blockers. If you do not hit the pause button or cast your spell quickly enough, then you have missed your chance (for now). The game simply will not let you cast spells while declaring blockers.